# What does a computer program (for example, Word) do, when the user does not type anything?

Tags: computers

That's the whole question. When I type anything the interrupt comes into play. But what happens when I do not type anything but the program still runs?

Comment: Better asked on a coding stack or superuser ...

Comment: It sleeps/waits for an interrupt.

Comment: This question belongs on another Stack Exchange site such as Computer Science or Progarmmers.

Comment: If nothing else must be done by any other software element, the CPU will reach a "halt" instruction that forces it to idle until next interruption. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)

Comment: This question should be on another site about programming as a program such as Word is just one of many tasks operating within a complex operating system and as such is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: The application is probably in something like a wait loop, but the processor will still be processing a lot of traffic over USB, Ethernet etc. and there will be a lot of processes running other than the application in question. This computer I'm typing on currently has 100 processes running and all it's doing at the moment is a couple browsers with multiple pages open.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then your CPU core or cores are either put to sleep (and really do *nothing*), or in a loop looking for input, handling a lot of other things, amongst which drivers, filesystems, network etc are just a few examples.

Really, modern processors range from the 100 MHz to 4 GHz range. Handling of input events (which have stopped issuing specific hardware interrupts a long time ago – around 1997, when USB became popular) is really the very least of the load of your CPU.

The title of your question demonstrates a misunderstanding: "Word" is just one of the many tasks your computer is running. The operating system "activates" one of these tasks, which then does some work, and at some point it either *yields* control back to the operating system, or control is forcefully brought back to the OS through an interrupt. At that point, the OS decides what to do – handle whatever brought control to it (for example, the task's question for data from a file, or the interrupt from a timer or the network card), and then go to sleep, or jump over to a different task, or jump over to the same task and so on.

That way, multiple things can run on a single processor core at once – you can have your browser open while you run Word, while network packets are still accepted, while your graphic card is still instructed to update the screen and so on.

Word doesn't "use" the CPU. The CPU executes Word's code. For some time, then it executes other code.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @ThePhoton not convinced it's off-topic! It's about the operation of processors, more than it is about the writing of software. Sure, a programmer *should* know this, but really, it's EEs that design CPUs.

Comment: The question asks what the "computer program" does, not what the processor does.

Comment: and my answer points out why it's the processor that does stuff; I think it fits well :) OP also showed they're actually wondering about the hardware side by mentioning interrupts. It's just that the mental separation from soft- and hardware wasn't as clear for OP.

Comment: it doesnt, The CPU doesn't know about user-input (at the level the OP is discussing re. MSWord). The OS does. When the OS determines it is appropriate to push a process down in priority in the scheduler it does.

Comment: Almost there @JonRB ....Word is an application written to an abstracted API. User input (mouse, keyboard, touch) is formed by a Driver (loaded by the OS). The OS supports drivers and API's, a Kernel may support hardware abstraction.   Word does not wait for user input ....it waits for messages relative to the window selection. I'd suggest the OP buy a book on Windows Internals ...he could start here for free: http://csit.udc.edu/~byu/UDC3529315/WindowsInternals-4e.pdf

Comment: @JackCreasey well I could have gone into the depths of what an OS does but... 550characters is way to slow. In short this isn't a CPU/Hardware behaviour, it is an OS/application behaviour and as such the question does not belong here and this reply should not have been made